# Directly redirect to a page based on some condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have already a `home` page, now I want to add a `homePlus` page controlled by a `localStorage` variable `alreadyShown`. The setting is, after `homePlus` is displayed for the first time, we set `alreadyShown` to `true`, as a result all the later loading of `homePlus` will directly redirect to the `home` page. I have the following code:

```
.state('homePlus', {
    url: '/homePlus',
    templateUrl: '/htmls/homePlus.html',
    controller: 'homePlusCtrl',
    resolve: {
        checkAlready: ['$window', function ($window) {
            if ($window.localStorage['alreadyShown'] === "true") {
                $window.location.href = "https://localhost:3000/home"
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

The above code does check `alreadyShown`. However, even though `alreadyShown` is `true`, it still shows the `homePlus` page for `0.5-1` second, before redirecting to `home`. Ideally, in this case I don't want to see `homePlus` page at all.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ui-router event  `$stateChangeStart` should be  work.
[angular.module.run](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

```
 app.run(['$rootScope' function ($rootScope) {       
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
             ...do something 
        });
    }]);
```